# Windows.Forms.Timer not working properly

Tags: c#, timer, messagebox

I am posting a sample code to decode a problem with a larger code.

I have a 2 seconds timer - System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Every 2 seconds i increment a global int by one, and show its value using MessageBox
If the int reaches 4, i turn off the main flag.

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool Play_On = false;
        int i = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.Text == "Play")
            {
                button1.Text = "Puase";
                Play_On = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Text = "Play";
                Play_On = false;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer MinResTimer = new Timer();

            {
                MinResTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MinResTimer_Elapsed);
                MinResTimer.Interval = 2000;
                MinResTimer.Enabled = true;
                MinResTimer.Start();
            }
        }
        public void MinResTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Play_On == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("timed"+ i.ToString());
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 4)
            {
                Play_On = false;
                button1.Text = "Play";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the flag isnt being turned off at all.
The output I am getting is Timed0 - In a messagebox, many times.
I think I have some problem with the messagebox - not sure

Could someone help me find out whats going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Move your increment of i++ to before you call MessageBox

Then you will see that you really want to protect the event from still firing while the message box is displayed.

so your new code would move the I++ to before the MessageBox and then you would disable and enable the timer before and after the message box is called.

Comment: I didnt get what you said. Why is the messagebox being there such a big problem? If i put the increment of i++ before the messagebox, the flag still isnt being turned off. If i disable and enable the timer, I may lose continuity, which i dont want to in my larger app

Comment: @noob I think you expect code after `MessageBox.Show` to be executed immediately and at the same time after you close the message box... Only one can happen - in case of message box code after the call will be executed after dialog is closed... You may want to create custom non-modal dialog box to get former behavior.

Comment: So the while the messagebox is displayed, the code after it will not run?

Answer (score 0):

```
    void MinResTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Play_On == true)
        {
            i++;
            MessageBox.Show("timed" + i.ToString());
        }
        if (i == 4)
        {
            Play_On = false;
            MinResTimer.Enabled = false;
            button1.Text = "Pause";
        }
    }  

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Play")
        {
            button1.Text = "Puase";
            MinResTimer.Enabled = true;
            i = 0;
            Play_On = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Text = "Play";
            MinResTimer.Enabled = false;
            Play_On = false;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT #1:**

```
    bool Play_On = false;
    int i = 0;
    Timer MinResTimer;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MinResTimer = new Timer();

        {
            MinResTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MinResTimer_Elapsed);
            MinResTimer.Interval = 2000;
            MinResTimer.Enabled = true;
            MinResTimer.Start();
        }
    }
    void MinResTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Play_On == true && i <= 4)
        {
            i++;
            MessageBox.Show("timed" + i.ToString());
        }
        if (i == 4)
        {
            Play_On = false;
            button1.Text = "Pause";
        }
    }  

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Play")
        {
            button1.Text = "Puase";
            Play_On = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Text = "Play";
            Play_On = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No i want the timer to be running, just not do anything if button1 is clicked.

Comment: Also ,your code gives an error, MinResTimer does not exist in the current context.

Comment: well if your going to use the code above, you would need to declare the `MinResTimer` variable first..Then in your `Form1_Load` event you will need to type this `MinResTimer = new Timer();` instead of `Timer MinResTimer = new Timer();

Answer (score 0):

When the messagebox show,then you didn't click the 'OK' button to close the messagebox, i++ can not do.So i always equals 0 before you click the 'OK' button on messagebox.

Comment: Exactly. Why is this happening?